# How can I make this menus dropdown items show vertical?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, navigation, navbar

I made this horizontal menu, and everything was nice and good, until I realized that I can't make the submenus appear vertical, can someone help me?

Here is the menu code:

```
<div id="nav_custom">
    <div id="nav_custom_wrapper"></div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">NEW ARRIVALS</a>

            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="#">SEQUIN DRESSES</a>
                <ul id="nav_custom_sub">
                    <li><a href="#">AVAILABLE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">EXAMPLES SOLD</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li><li>
            <a href="#">BOHO DRESSES</a>
                <ul id="nav_custom_sub">
                    <li><a href="#">AVAILABLE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">EXAMPLES SOLD</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </li><li>
            <a href="#">MOD DRESSES</a>
                <ul id="nav_custom_sub">
                    <li><a href="#">AVAILABLE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">EXAMPLES SOLD</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li><li>
            <a href="#">PSYCHEDELIC DRESSES</a>
                <ul id="nav_custom_sub">
                    <li><a href="#">AVAILABLE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">EXAMPLES SOLD</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li><li>
            <a href="#">COATS & JACKETS</a>
                <ul id="nav_custom_sub">
                    <li><a href="#">AVAILABLE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">EXAMPLES SOLD</a></li>
                </ul>
            <li>
            <a href="#">KIMONOS</a>
                <ul id="nav_custom_sub">
                    <li><a href="#">AVAILABLE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">EXAMPLES SOLD</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the css that I have used:

```
#nav_custom {
text-decoration: none;
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 49px;
color: #000;
display: block;
padding: 10px;
width: 960px;
margin-left: -35px;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: center;
width: auto;
}
#nav_custom_wrapper {
width: 960px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: center;
}
#nav_custom ul{
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
position: relative;
}
#nav_custom ul li{
display: inline-block;

}
#nav_custom ul li:hover{
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
}
#nav_custom ul li a,visited{
color: #BA7145;
padding: 15px;
text-decoration: none;
}
#nav_custom ul li a:hover{
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
}
#nav_custom ul li:hover ul{
display: block;
}
#nav_custom ul ul{
display: none;
position: absolute;
margin-top: -25px;
margin-left: -50px;
text-align: center;
color: #4f4f4f;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `inline-block` on the `#nav_custom ul li`

See fiddle for working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Tv77g/

Inline-block works similarly to floats, which is why they were stacking left to right next to each other instead of one on top of each other.

I didn't go through to adjust your children. I don't know how the menu is supposed to display. Most likely the children (`#nav_custom ul ul`) would have the margins adjusted. You can remove `text-align:center;` on `#nav_custom` to make the menu completely left aligned.

To set this only on children, add

`#nav_custom_sub li {
display: block !important;
}`

This will override the inline-block for only the children (in the dropdown). You will have to adjust the margins to make them appear correctly.

Comment: I did this too, the problem is that I don't want the menu to be vertical, only its children/submenus, and by doing this everything becomes vertical

Comment: `#nav_custom_sub li {
display: block !important;}` doing this will override the inline-block elements for the list items of the `#nav_custom_sub`. You will still have to adjust the margins for `#nav_custom ul ul`. (Fiddle has been updated).